# Agora One to One Voice Call in Java Script and Provide Notification

Tags: javascript, java, agora.io

I am Using Agora using Java Script.
Agora One to One Voice Call in Java Script and Provide Notification but how to send and received notification from one user to another user and How to get identification a call or chat in Agora

Answer (score 0):

You can send a call invitation to notify a user to be accepted or rejected using the Agora RTM SDK.

Documentation Link: https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/rtm_invite_web?platform=Web

Sample App: https://github.com/AgoraIO-Usecase/Video-Calling